# update dom not working with $watch

Tags: angularjs, watch

i try to update dom with data from api, but i get "$watch is not defined" here is my ctrl

```
app.controller('counter', ['$scope', 'factory', function ($scope, factory) {
    factory.get(function (res) {
        $scope.proizvedeno = res;
        $scope.output = $scope.proizvedeno.total_energy_output;

        $scope.countTo = $scope.output;
        $scope.countFrom = 0;
$scope.$watch("output", $scope.countTo)
console.log($watch);

        $scope.reCount = function () {
            $scope.countFrom = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 300);
            $scope.countTo = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 7000) - Math.ceil(Math.random() * 600);
        }; }]);
```

I try to add watch function, to automaticly update dom, but this is not working. Can someone help me pls.

Comment: remove the console.log($watch);

Comment: You are not creating a variable called `$watch` anywhere that can be logged. I suggest you read more on what Angular watches are and how the operate.

Comment: i read from https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope, and i dont see where is var $watch is declared. Can u pls hel me? Thnx @thalaivar too

Comment: $watch is method of $scope or $rootScope. There is no such variable.

Comment: thanke you, i add var scope = $rootScope; and declare scope.$watch("output", $scope.countTo);  and still dont work

Comment: Why are you printing $watch here? $scope.$watch("output", $scope.countTo);console.log($watch);

Comment: I Want to see if angularjs go In function.  Its only fol example,  i delete console.Log

Comment: @Check my answer... try the reformed code and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Let me put this as answer, so it brings more `clarity` to the question.

Your actual **code**:

```
app.controller('counter', ['$scope', 'factory', function ($scope, factory) {
    factory.get(function (res) {
        $scope.proizvedeno = res;
        $scope.output = $scope.proizvedeno.total_energy_output;

        $scope.countTo = $scope.output;
        $scope.countFrom = 0;
        $scope.$watch("output", $scope.countTo) //Changed this
        console.log($watch); //removed this line

        $scope.reCount = function () {
            $scope.countFrom = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 300);
            $scope.countTo = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 7000) - Math.ceil(Math.random() * 600);
        }; }]);
```

**Reformed one:**

```
app.controller('counter', ['$scope', 'factory', function ($scope, factory) {
    factory.get(function (res) {
        $scope.proizvedeno = res;
        $scope.output = $scope.proizvedeno.total_energy_output;

        $scope.countTo = $scope.output;
        $scope.countFrom = 0;
        $scope.$watch("output", 
                 function handleChange( newValue, oldValue ) {
                    console.log( "$scope.output:", newValue );
        })

        $scope.reCount = function () {
            $scope.countFrom = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 300);
            $scope.countTo = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 7000) - Math.ceil(Math.random() * 600);
        }; }]);
```

Comment: Thanke you,  i will try when i Come home Now im leave office

Comment: Hi i use this, but there is no change in dom after i add new data to database. only after refresh... i Want live data. Thnx

Comment: hey @Thalaivar are you there?

Answer (score 0):

hi guys i fix this with timeout, i don't know is this best solution but this working for me. Thnx to all

```
app.controller('counter', ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout',  function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
$scope.reload = function () {              //add new function for timer
$http.get(serviceBase + 'live-stats').
    success(function (res) {
         $scope.proizvedeno = res;

            $scope.wireless_charging_count = $scope.proizvedeno.wireless_charging_count;
            $scope.countTo3 = $scope.wireless_charging_count;
            $scope.countFrom3 = 0;
            $scope.reCount = function () {
            $scope.countFrom3 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 300);
                    $scope.countTo3 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 7000) - Math.ceil(Math.random() * 600);
            };

         });
         var reload = $timeout(function(){          //set here $timeout
            $scope.reload();
            }, 5000);
            $scope.$on('$destroy', function(){      //must cancel $timeout
$timeout.cancel(reload);
});  
     };
    $scope.reload();     
}]);
```

U must cancel timer, or you will have problem like me :) , after change route timer still working and reload data from url. Thnx to everyone